Security in Jakarta EE: Why is the login page not being displayed?
I want to secure my web application deployed on GlassFish server 7.0.13. Despite of followind all the steps required for implementing a form authentication, from adding the users in the realm file allowed to access my resource pages to writing my web.xml descriptor, described in the official spec of Jakarta EE 9 page:
enter link description here
All my pages are blocked and the login page isn't even displayed.
Could you help me understand what's wrong?
here is my web.xml page :
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
    version="5.0"
>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <display-name>Ricky's Restaurant</display-name>
    <description>The menu and online ordering system for Ricky's Restaurant</description>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Security roles used by this web application -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>users' allowed pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/result.xhtml</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/thankYou.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>staff pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/processorders.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/failed-login.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
</web-app>

